redirect to different url after order received or/ Redirect to custom Thankyou page after WooCommerce orders paid
After successful payment through Razorpay payment gateway, I need to redirect to my custom created Thankyou page, instead of Razorpay payment gateway plugin default redirect URL.
My problem illustrated: screen recorded video
Here is what I tried in functions.php file:
/* Redirect WooCommerce to a custom page after checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 're_redirect_woo_checkout');
function re_redirect_woo_checkout( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'custom thankyou page url here';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}

It work which have zero payment product that doesn't need razorpay gateway to popup to pay, it auto redirect instant when clicking proceed to checkout. But when clicking proceed to checkout for payment above zero cost then razorpay gateway popup required to pay through different paying facility, after successfull payment through razorpay payment gateway it's not redirecting to my specific choice of page (custom thank you page).

i tryed to implemet your answered code but not working : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bgyv-FWbZrQA4ibimt8JIGBZrLqSg2Ju/view?usp=sharing

on successfull payment for zero cost product as well as above zero cost product in both case i see its redirect to order recieved page but after few second in costed product its take few second to processing and completeing payment once its verifys as completed then its auto gets redirected to dashboard page and not get redirect in zero cost product. so i have no control for redirecting url after order recieved page.

i found some solution i found redirecting enable/desable redirect button in tutor lms plugin, from this if i enable option it work correctly redirecting to its enrolled course dashboard page if desable its do nothing only show order received page after payment completed. but i unable to figureout how this feature they able to do that , what code they writen.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hAOMQlpNymSWROeQ07pKD6dE-LtwXZGS/view?usp=sharing

finally i came up with this code and its worked
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_thank_you_redirect' );
function wc_thank_you_redirect(){ 
  if( isset( $_GET['key'] ) && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) { //change order-received to your endpoint if you will change it in the future 
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] );
    if ( ! empty( $order_id ) ) {
      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
      $order_status = $order->get_status();
        
        if ('failed' == $order_status ) {  //failed order status
          wp_redirect( 'your custom failed page url here' ); //change url here
          exit;
        } else {
          wp_redirect( 'your custom thank you page url here' ); //change url here for other statuses redirect
          exit;
        }
      }
    }
  }
//code end for redirect after order received

